# Designing a static timer for javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript

```html
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(1);
include("database.php");

extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
extract($_SESSION);
/*$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_que") or die(mysql_error());
if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs))
{
unset($_SESSION[qn]);
exit;
}*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Quiz</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<?php
include("header.php");
extract($_SESSION);
$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_res where
login='$login'",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
$tt="$row[3]";
}

if($tt=="1")
{
echo "You have already taken the test.Cannot take test again!";
exit;
}
?>








<?php


include("timer.php");



$query="select * from mst_que";


$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_que") or die(mysql_error());


 
  if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
  {
    mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
    $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
 
    mysql_query("insert into usr_ans(que_id,ques_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]', '$row[5]','$row[6]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($ans==$row[6])
    {
       $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
    }
    $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;

  }
  else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans))
  {
    mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
    $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
    mysql_query("insert into usr_ans(que_id,ques_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]', '$row[5]','$row[6]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($ans==$row[6])
    {
       $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
    }
    echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
    $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
    echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
    echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
    $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
    echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_query("insert into mst_res(login,test_date,score,test_taken) values('$login','".date("y/m/d")."',$_SESSION[trueans],1)") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<h1 align=center><a href=index.php> Thank you for taking the online test</a> </h1>";
    unset($_SESSION[qn]);
  
    unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
    exit;
  }


mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
$row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";

$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Question ".  $n .": $row[1]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[2]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[5]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Next Question'></form>";
else
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'></form>";
echo "</table></table>";
?>





</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently working on a quiz project in PHP and HTML.
I'm retrieving questions from the PHP database to be displayed as options in browser.
I just want to implement a simple timeout. I have figured out how to create a timer and redirect control to another page once the timer runs out but since the questions are being retrieved from the database(PHP), the page reloads everytime on the browser and everytime this happens my timer restarts(when next question is pressed!).
I would want to know as to how to keep the timer running even though it crosses through various other pages.

timer code i have used:

```js
<?php
$dateFormat = "d F Y -- g:i a";
$targetDate = time() + (01*60);//Change the 25 to however many minutes you want to countdown
$actualDate = time();
$secondsDiff = $targetDate - $actualDate;
$remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
$remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
$remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
$remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));
$actualDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$actualDate);
$targetDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$targetDate);
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quiz System</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


  var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>  
  var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
  var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
  var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?> 
function setCountDown ()
{
  seconds--;
  if (seconds < 0){
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59
  }
  if (minutes < 0){
      hours--;
      minutes = 00
  }
  if (hours < 0){
      days--;
      hours = 00
  }
  document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = hours+" hours, "+minutes+" minutes, "+seconds+" seconds";
  SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
  if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
     //window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue."); // change timeout message as required
    window.location = "http://localhost:8080/LL_project/timeup.php" // Add your redirect url
  } 

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="setCountDown();">

 <div id="remain"><?php echo "$remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes, $remainingSeconds seconds";?></div>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code/timer is working just fine! the only problem is when i click on next question, the next set of questions are loaded and the timer resets.

Answer (score 0):

Before reloading the next page, what about storing the time left on the timer in a cookie, once the next page has loaded, check if a timer-cookie exists. If yes, resume the timer with that given value, otherwise start a new one?

Pseudo: before `window.location = "http://localhost:8080/LL_project/timeup.php"` add `document.cookie="?t="getTimerTimeLeft()`. As you go to timeup.php, look if document.cookie contains "t", if it does, start the timer from that time, otherwise, start a new one.

Not an ideal solution but the first that came to my mind.

You could pass the time left as a parameter in the URL but unless tampering is not an issue for you, don't know how viable that is as a solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other means? Please help! it would be much appreciated! Is there any way i can use a samll temporary memory (browser's memory) or sessions?

Comment: Why not the two solutions I posted? Would make it clear what kind of solution you're seeking

Comment: Okay. Can i get some elaboration with respect to code on how to deal with checking cookies in timeup.php and starting my timer from that time onwards ?

Comment: In timeup.php do:
`if($_COOKIE[t]) { $time=intval($_COOKIE['t']); } else { $time=$defaulttime; }`

and in your JS file set up your timer as such:

`var defaultTime = 1000;
var timeLeft=defaultTime;
var interval1 = window.setInterval(()=>{
    timeLeft = timeLeft-1;
},1000);
var timeout1 = window.setTimeout("setCountDown()",defaultTime);`

And before you go to timeup.php do:
`document.cookie="t="+timeLeft;
clearInterval(interval1);
clearTimeout(timeout1);`

Something to this effect. This isn't 100% code, but should give an idea of the idea

Comment: Sir , just making it clear.. all the questions to the quiz are being retrieved from phpmyadmin database but for every question it has to reload(When next question is pressed)and that's when the timer is being reset. timeup.php is just to display the end of time. Im just saying , i thought i missed that out

Comment: If you understand the answer it should be easy to implement it into your own code. I can't make my answer any more clear, sorry. Two timers. An interval that counts how much time has passed, and one that calls the timeout after the time's up. Once user finishes the question, store the time left from the interval in a cookie, and in the next page retrieve it

Comment: Okay sir, i will try to implement it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store the time when the user started with the questions in a cookie. It can be session cookie or just normal cookie.
And every time the page loads, you take this value as a start time.

But keep in mind that this is not very secure, as user can delete his cookies.
If you want a more secure solution, make sure to store the start time in the database and return it with each request.

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer. I'm just trialing out on this project so it doesnt matter if its secure or not. so if you can please provide me the code to do that(implementing your answer using cookies), it would help!